# DateListLogPlot fails on more than one data series in version 11.0.1

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time

**Fixed in 11.2**

---

`DateListLogPlot` is not able to plot more than one data series in 11.0.1. However it can plot in versions 11.0.0 and 10.4.1.

With

```
data = {{{3631651200, 99.9578}, {3660508800, 100.731}}, 
        {{3663187200, 101.221}, {3676233600, 104.22 }}};
```

Then

```
DateListLogPlot[data]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However

```
DateListLogPlot[First@data]
```

and

```
DateListLogPlot[Last@data]
```

produce plots.

Can anyone else confirm? (Win 7 Ent with Mma 11.0.1)

**Update** Confirmed bug. CASE:3727110

Comment: Doesn't work in 11.0.1 for me (same errors), works in 10.4.1. You should report this to WRI.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm. It has been reported.

Comment: Looks like it only happens when all the datasets have exactly two points.

Comment: For a workaround: `Show[DateListLogPlot /@ data, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Could I don't your code are using which method in ``GeneralUtilities`PrintUsages["System`DateListLogPlot"]``?

Answer (score 1):

fyi, fixed  in 11.2

---

version 11.1.1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Fixed in 11.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
data={{{3631651200},99.9578},{{3660508800},100.731},{{3663187200},101.221},{{3676233600},104.22}}
```

DateListLogPlot[data] produces:

[image]